# PHP: зачем нужем экранированный ноль после пробела?

Tags: php

В Yii2 есть метод [`camel2words`](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/helpers/BaseInflector.php#L360):

```
public static function camel2words($name, $ucwords = true)
{
    $label = trim(strtolower(str_replace([
        '-',
        '_',
        '.',
    ], ' ', preg_replace('/(?<![A-Z])[A-Z]/', ' \0', $name))));
    return $ucwords ? ucwords($label) : $label;
}
```

Зачем здесь производится замена на `пробел + экранированный ноль`, почему не просто на `пробел`?

Answer (score 3):

<s>Емаё, вот это я переработался ...</s>

Экранированный ноль в данном случае является ссылкой на подмаску:

> `replacement` может содержать ссылки вида \\n, либо (начиная с PHP 4.0.4) $n, причем последний вариант предпочтительней. Каждая такая ссылка будет заменена на подстроку, соответствующую n-ой подмаске. n может принимать значения от 0 до 99, причем ссылка \\0 (либо $0) соответствует вхождению всего шаблона. Подмаски нумеруются слева направо, начиная с единицы. Для использования обратного слеша, его необходимо продублировать (строка PHP "\\\\").

http://php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-replace.php

**UPDATE**

При вставке цитаты с PHP.Net она опубликовалась не совсем точно: «съелись» обратные слэши. Это заметили в комментариях к ответу. Сейчас всё поправил — цитата точная ... Тем не менее, как я отметил, работают оба варианта (то есть `\0` и `\\0`):

```
$str = 'AaaBbbCcc';

echo preg_replace('/(?<![A-Z])[A-Z]/', ' ', $str); // aa bb cc

echo "\n";

echo preg_replace('/(?<![A-Z])[A-Z]/', ' \0', $str); // Aaa Bbb Ccc

echo "\n";

echo preg_replace('/(?<![A-Z])[A-Z]/', ' \\0', $str); // Aaa Bbb Ccc
```

https://repl.it/Cjmh

<s>Почему так, не знаю, думаю это стоит отдельного вопроса.</s>

Comment: Эм.. Но ведь правильно будет `\\0`, а не `\0`?

Comment: @Qwertiy,.. честно сказать, даже не приметил (засыпаю уже) ... Но, тем не менее, работают оба варианта: https://repl.it/CjgA.

Comment: @Qwertiy, хм,.. так всё правильно ведь: `Для использования обратного слеша, его необходимо продублировать (строка PHP "\\")` — это про использование обратного слэша в строке замены, а не про ссылку на подмаску ...

Comment: В документации по твоей ссылке слеши удвоены: `\\n` и ``\\\\``. Что логично, т. к. аргумент-то строка. Либо там очень магический парсер...